# Matlab sscanf error

Tags: matlab, scanf

The following code is used to read and label data from an eeg file.
Matlab gives the following error:

> Error using sscanf
>   First argument must be a string.

Is there a way to fix this?

```
%% File Names reading and label generation 

dataFolder= 'SMNI_CMI_TRAIN/';
fileNames = dir([dataFolder 'c*.*']);

lbl = sscanf(cat(1,fileNames.name)','co2%c%d.rd.%d');
status = lbl(1:3:end);
id = lbl(2:3:end);
ids = unique(id);
trial = lbl(3:3:end);
```

Comment: Tried `{ fileNames.name }` ?

Comment: Could you give three of the file names for example?